# SuiteScript Governance & Scheduled Scripts

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I understand the idea of governance and how to check the usage points of a script and, if it's running out, reschedule it using the task module.

My questions are two:

- when I invoke the submit method to schedule the re-running of my script, does the current instance of my script terminate immediately?
- when the time comes for the re-running of my script, does NetSuite just re-run the entire thing, from the top? Or is there a way it can pick up where it was, with the same data in the same variables, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the answer to your questions

> - when I invoke the submit method to schedule the re-running of my script, does the current instance of my script terminate immediately?

The current instance will run until it finishes it won't get terminated, on the contrary, the new invoke will not run the schedule script in the first place you will receive FAILED_TO_SUBMIT_JOB_REQUEST_1 ERROR if there any instance still runing.

> - When the time comes for the re-running of my script, does NetSuite just re-run the entire thing, from the top? Or is there a way it can
>   pick up where it was, with the same data in the same variables, etc.?

Normally it will re-run the entire thing, and if your script got terminated for error or any reason, then re-running it will start from the top again.